# No module named numpy in command prompt even after installing it

Tags: python, numpy, pip, command-prompt

I have installed numpy module using pip command.

[image: here is the image]

I typed app.py in command prompt, it says no module named numpy

this is the code for app.py

[image]

Comment: I already installed flask and other modules

Comment: are you calling the same python? and how did you install numpy?

Comment: yeah same python, I used pip install numpy

Answer (score 1):

To be sure to use the right version of Python, you can call directly the Python that you use to install numpy like this :

```
C:\users\aniruddh srivatsa\python.exe app1.py
```

Comment: Thanks, Now numpy shows no error but "no module named xgboost " is appearning. I already imported xgboost (pip install xgboost). Is there any solutions for that

Comment: Use ```pip list``` to list all the packages installed. Check if xgboost is in the list